# Create a scheduled report with a infinite JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, report, cognos

I'm trying to create a new scheduled report and I've one doubt about it: How can I create a script on it with a loop that runs a function every 10 seconds? Something like:

```
var value = 1;
while(value > 0){
    setTimeout(function(){myFunction()},10000);
    value = value -1;
}
```

When I just run my report into the report studio (without schedule) this script executes successfully, but after the schedule it doesn't work anymore. Someone know why is this happening or have any other idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no infinite loop in your code. `while` is executed untill the condition can be evaluated `false`. In your case that happens after the first round. You shouldn't even try to use an infinite loop, it would block the whole browser and finally browser will crash.

Comment: Sorry about the "infinite", It was an old idea. I just want to execute the function sometimes

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  I'm trying to understand what you would do with JavaScript in a scheduled report.

Comment: I want to pass a parameter from a report to another one through a portlet channel. I've already done it before, but it wasn't a scheduled report. Then, I was thinking about create a javascript to check the parameter change. But, after the report schedule, my script doesn't execute anymore. I've already tried both functions (setInterval and setTimeout)

Comment: Javascript will not run in a scheduled (background report). It only runs when the report is actually run interactively in a persons web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) instead of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

Also your while loop is not needed.

Just use this instead:
`setInterval(myFunction, 10000);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the same structure, you can use `setTimeout` to make it slightly recursive:

```
var repeatedFunction = function(){
  // Do something
  setTimeout(repeatedFunction, 10 * 1000);
};
```

but you're better off using `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function(){
  // do something
}, 10 * 1000);
```

and if you need to cancel it, store the interval:

```
var repeatedFunction = setInterval(function(){
  // do something
}, 10 * 1000);

// .. something happened; need to cancel
clearTimeout(repeatedFunction);
```